# Site com uma barra branca no final

Tags: html, css

Boa tarde pessoal, estou desenvolvendo um site pessoal na qual estou com um probleminha, mas já procurei e não consegui resolver, acontece que meu site, em resoluções maiores, fica com uma section branca enorme abaixo do footer, porém não estou conseguindo editar essa section e nem selecioná-la no chrome developer tools, segue fotos, isso so acontece em resoluções maiores que 1366x768 , e quanto maior for a resolução, maior a barra

[image: Essa é em 1920x1080]
1920x1080

[image: Essa é e, 2560x1080]
2560x1080

o site também está hospedado no servidor do github, pode acessar clicando [aqui](https://isaacmeira.github.io/personalwb/)

se puderem me ajudar por gentileza...
Desde já agradeço
muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é na `<div class="carousel-inner " id="inner">` que está extrapolando a altura da página, criando um overflow maior do que o conteúdo da página, e por consequência criando um espaço vazio após o `footer`.

Resolva definindo a altura em 100% para que não fique maior que seu contêiner:

```
#inner{
   height: 100%
}
```

Você pode testar executando este código no console:

```
$("#inner").css("height", "100%");
```

Verá que o problema some instantaneamente.

Comment: Show de bola! resolveu aqui pra min, muito obrigado amigo ^^